# plotting time and temperature in xy plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a xy plot where x axis contain temperature values(first column) and y axis contain time in hr:min:sec(second column) .

```
8.8900  06:09:95.50
9.4500  06:09:00.56
10.5800 08.06:95.48
11.6500 09:07:73.58
56.3650 00:08:00.47
85.7823 07:01:03.23
```

I just want to plot a xy plot.

I tried code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.loadtxt("inpdata.txt")
plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

But it does not give plot.hope experts may help.Thanks.

Comment: Wouldnt it make more sense to plot time in x axis and temp in y axis?

Comment: yes it can be @BijayRegmi, it would be better

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to use `pandas`.

Load the file as whitespace delimited file into `pandas.DataFrame` object as:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('inpdata.txt', names=['temp', 'time'], delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then create a line plot with `time` as x axis:

```
df.plot.line(x='time')
```

and show the plot

```
plt.show()
```